# VBA get multiple datas from ComboBox

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I am trying to get datas from a ComboBox where you can select several data.

My code is the following :

```
Dim ind As Integer
Dim bl As Boolean
ind = 0
While ind < Forms!Rec!CONTACT.ListCount
bl = Forms!Rec!CONTACT.Selected(ind)
If bl Then
txt1 = txt1 + "Contact : " & Forms!Rec!CONTACT.Column(4, ind) & " " & Forms!Rec!CONTACT.Column(2, ind) & vbCrLf & Forms!Rec!CONTACT.Column(3, ind) & vbCrLf & Forms!Rec!CONTACT.Column(6, ind)
End If
ind = ind + 1
Wend
```

For some reason the boolean value is always false.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the above code located? Is the form still loaded when this code is executed?

Comment: I just realised I forge to say hello ...

The code is located in another code that aims to generate a powerpoint from datas in the form. The form is still open when I run the code.

Comment: I think that you can only have one selected item in a ComboBox. You may want to use a ListBox instead.

Comment: The form is created using Access HIM, so I don't now how to change from a ComboBox to a ListBox

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that familiar with Access VBA. I suggest adding the "access-v ba" tag to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I did some test : you can select several items either with a ComboBox or a ListBox. I still don't understand why the boolean value is always false

Comment: You *can't* select multiple Items with a combo box. 
You can with a multiselect listbox, but you need completely different code to return the values.

Comment: Actually you can do it in Access 2016. But I also tried to do it with a ListBox and I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what was wrong.

You have to use ComboBox.OldValue instead of Selected or ItemsSelected.

using this particular function you'll have an array with all the positions of the selcted items.

Thanks for your help ;)